Add an in-page / lightbox-like image viewer
When we open an attached image in a post, it opens on the same tab.
It would be nice to have an "image viewer" with standard controls like "zoom", using the Esc key to exit, arrow key navigation if there were multiple images attached, etc..
Ex: Answer, Question

An answer to a related question notes that there is a userscript available for this, though that is of course less convenient than having it built in.

on MSE: Support showing image in original size in overlay and Images should be automatically rescaled and the full size linked or put into a lightbox

@RyanM Samuel has way too many userscripts :D I thought I have most of them (besides the mod-only ones), but no, I missed this one. Thank you for this.

Using a decent web browser such as Firefox and then middle mouse click the picture should solve all your problems. Why should SO invent features already available in decent browsers?
